# How to get Git pre-push hook refname

Tags: git

I am using pre-push hook to generate change-log automatically from the annotated tags. I want to check if the ref being pushed is `tag` or not. 
The arguments passed to pre-push hook doesn't contain the refname being pushed. How to get it?

Pushing annotated tag using `git push origin <tag>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bash shell, you could use the following code to get what you need:

```
#!/bin/bash

remote=$1
url=$2
#above are the 2 parameters
#below are from the stdin
while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
   #if pushing a tag, local_ref would be refs/tags/...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

At https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks, says "list of to-be-updated refs passed through stdin." Look at the template pre-push.sample hook under .git/hooks.